# Setting image source in windows phone

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, lockscreen

I am trying to set source for an image. The catch here is the Uri for the image am receiving. The data is coming from the device lockscreen. The uri is

```
res://UIXMobileAssets{ScreenResolution}!lock.sms.dualsim1.png
```

The regular code

```
Image imgLogo = new Image();
imgNotificationThreeLogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(spliNotifications[1], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

throws exception "host name could not be parsed". Has anyone had any experience on this. Please help.

TIA.
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
        Image image = new Image();
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.UriSource=new Uri (spliNotifications[1],UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        image.Source = bmp;
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if there was some explanation of how this code solves the problem better than the user's existing code.

Comment: I do not understand how this is any different from what is already in place? And also, tried it, doesn't work!

Comment: Do you debug the code ? Is image path value is coming? What you are getting in spliNotifications[1]?